# Error: file doesn't exist and no such file or directory python

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

I have files (data1.txt,data2.txt,....) that I want to iterate, so

I did that:

```
path='mypath' # not the same python project directory
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
   for file in files:
       print(file)
       f = open(file)
```

despite the files exist,this shows:

```
data1.txt

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data1.txt'
```

I have also a function where I want to use these files, this function works fine when I use a single file that is located in the same python project directory.

```
  process_r=pro_r("data1.txt")
```

however, when I use it in the for loop above, process_r=pro_r(file), it shows this error: file doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

The problem is os.walk returns the relative path to the given path. So you need to use this path:

```
path='mypath' # not the same python project directory
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
   for file in files:
       print(file)
       f = open(path + "/" + file)  # / or \\ depends on your OS
```

Comment: avoid joining your path manually. See my answer for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

you need to join root, and file to get the correct path for your files:

```
path='mypath' # not the same python project directory
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        print(root, file)
        f = open(os.path.join(root, file))
```